# Join tables on Oracle ROWID

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 tables A and B in Oracle 11g.  Table B holds the exact same data as Table A but with additional ROWID column which the ROWID of Table A.

I am going to change values of a column say colx in Table B. And then update colx in table A by joining table A and table B with the ROWID's.

Now, ROWID is encoded. Should I convert the ROWID to char  ? How do I do a join between table A and table B when one is a column and the other is Oracle ROWID pseudocolumn.

```
UPDATE tablea ta
   SET (colx) = (SELECT colx FROM tableb tb WHERE ta.rowid = tb.rowid)
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM tableb tb
     WHERE ta.rowid = tb.rowid )
```

Comment: You probably don't want to store ROWIDs for a long period of time, as they are physical data that may change independently of your logical data. For example, if someone ran a `MOVE` on the table to change a property, all the ROWIDs would change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, ROWID is encoded.

DOn't you use standard oracle type ROWID? If - yes, you don't need to convert it.
For example, your table B has column TAB_A_ROWID which contains rowid of related record in table A. So you can easily join them:

```
select *
from A join B on B.TAB_A_ROWID = A.rowid
```

Btw, in you code I see "ta.rowid = tb.rowid"

> ```
> UPDATE tablea ta
>   SET (colx) = (SELECT colx FROM tableb tb WHERE ta.rowid = tb.rowid)
> ```

but rowid is pseudocolumn, You can't add column rowid. so you specified both of them - real rowids, not from own column.

Answer (score 1):

ROWID is a pseudo-column that represents the data's physical location in a data block. It is NOT constant, and should not be used for any referential integrity or joins.

> if you update the partition key and the update causes the row to move
> from one partition to another - the rowid will CHANGE.
>
> If you use alter table t shrink space compact, the rowid could change
>
> If you use alter table t move, the rowid could change (even without
> enable row movement)
>
> If you use flashback table t to ...., the rowid could change.

ROWID should only be used - if ever - in combination with a true primary key. It should never be used *as* a primary key or instead of a true primary key.

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:53140678334596

Comment: It is a one time thing. Can this be achieved ? There are no primary keys, hence depending on ROWID